# Javascript: How to make only check box on-screen checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a 200 rows table, which is paged into 20 pages (10 rows each page). Each of these row has a check box. I use jPage so all the table is still there, only get hidden by "display:none". I have written a function to select all check box (with some previous conditions attached), something like this:

```
$('#masterCbox').click(function () {
  if($(this).is(':checked')) {
    $('.childCbox').prop('checked', false);
    $('.select-y').children('.childtd').children('.childCbox').prop('checked', true);
  } else 
    $('.childCbox').prop('checked', false);
});
```

This will check all rows that have class="select-y".

However, it's required that only check boxes on-screen are going to be checked (check boxes belong to rows of displaying page). How am I going to accomplish that?

Comment: can you tell us how you're making the other table as hidden I mean where does this 'display: none' been applied to

Comment: Amend your selector(s) so it checks the appropriate `parent`'s `display` CSS attribute and does not select those.

Comment: You could make sure that all checkboxes in hidden pages have the "disabled" flag set to `true`, so that they won't be posted when the form is submitted.

Comment: Which element is `display:none`?  I would find some means of using JQueries `not()` function to exclude those checkboxes that are children of hidden elements

Answer (score 1):

You can use the :visible selector in JQuery to see if something is visible or not.

Answer (score 1):

Check if it's visible, and just check if it has a parent somewhere matching `.select-y` instead of all the `children()` stuff :

```
$('#masterCbox').click(function () {
   if( this.checked ) {
       $('.childCbox').prop('checked', false).filter(function() {
           return $(this).is(':visible') && $(this).closest('.select-y').length;
       }).prop('checked', true);
  } else {
       $('.childCbox').prop('checked', false);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can apply a filter to check if your rows are visible :

```
  $('.select-y').is(':visible').children('.childtd').children('.childCbox').prop('checked', true);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
$('.select-y .childtd').children('.childCbox:visible').prop('checked', true);
```